# How to change the width of custom table cell loaded from nib?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nib

I want a custom table cell, and it just filled with an image. And I use nib file to create the custom cell. The problem is that, the cell's width doesn't fit with tableview width.

[The actual cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am71Z.png)

As you can see, the image is not at the center of my cell. When I log some information, I found it is the cell do not fit with the screen width.

Here is my code for cell :

```
@implementation IntroductViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)resizeWithWidth:(NSInteger)width {
    self.contentView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, width / 3);

    [self setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

}

@end
```

And in cellForRowAtIndex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    IntroductViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"introductcell"];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell) {
        NSArray *nibs = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IntroductViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nibs objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpeg"];
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpeg"];
    }

    [cell resizeWithWidth:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width];

    NSLog(@"The width is:%f", cell.frame.size.width);

    return cell;
}
```

The log information is here:

```
2016-07-09 12:17:12.728 Test[13594:2316211] The width is:750.000000
2016-07-09 12:17:12.732 Test[13594:2316211] The width is:750.000000
```

Actually, the width is the original width of my image, and I want it has the same width with cell, so I add contraints to make it has equal width and height with cell, does this influenced my cell? How can I resize the cell to make it fit with the screen width? I would really appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

Comment: can you please upload an image what you exactly want to do?

Comment: In fact, I just want the cell to fit the width of my screen, and its height maintain 1/3 of its width, that is what I want. @Arun Kumar

Comment: The width of a cell is always equal to table view width and the height of cell can only be changed by a delegate method of tableview that is heightForRowAtIndexpath. So if you want to change height of a cell use this delegate method.

Comment: But when I print the information in cellForRowAtIndex, the log shows the width is more than screen. The iPhone 6s screen's width is 375px, but here, it show that my cell is 750.

Comment: The thing is, that is the actual size of cell which you have created in nib. When you print the information it always show you the original size of that cell what you have created in nib . But actual width of cell totally managed by tableview and height of cell is managed by delegate method which I have mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: OK，so that's why my image cannot get correct frame, thank you!